# Navigation through anchor tag within a aspx page through ASP.NET Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, anchor

I have a web form with some `TextBoxes` and `CheckBoxList`. I want to navigate to specific portion of the page. I put `<a name="SpecificPortion"></a>` anchor to that part. Now i want, when i click the `SaveButton` (It is an ASP.NET Control) it should do its specific functionality and also navigate to the `SpecificPortion`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a web method to your page and for button make it normal HTML button call javascript function which call Web method to save, after success move your focus to a control in specific portion.

For Page methods follow

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/21456-Page-Method.aspx

http://aspalliance.com/1922_PageMethods_In_ASPNET_AJAX.3

& within the success function write document.getElementById('txtYourElement').focus().

Here 'txtYourElement' is the id of any HTML control on client side.

Hope this makes sense to you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but i am totally unaware from javascript.

Comment: @SaadQureshi If you wanna do web development then you should start learning Javascript ,its absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Response.Redirect()` and redirect to the same page, specifying the `SpecficPortion` anchor.

```
Response.Redirect("MyPageName.aspx#SpecificPortion")
```

Comment: this is causing some problems. like my controls are not showing `Text` properties and some other controls problem

Comment: Response.Redirect would postback and because of which your controls might not be loaded properly.

Comment: @Curt Response.Redirect makes a postback which results in control state lost.